# Is ParseException only thrown for conversion from string to date?

Tags: java, parseexception

I'm trying to become clear about `ParseException`. Its example focus is "convert from string to date", and I also found:

> This is a checked exception and it can occur when you fail to parse a
>   `String` that is ought to have a special format.

But I cannot find any example for another case!!!

So can you help me clear this case? Any another case that uses `ParseException`?

Comment: What's in the string, and what's the format you're trying to parse?

Comment: Some of the classes in the `java.text` package have got methods that may throw a `ParseException`, including `NumberFormat` and `MessageFormat`. You may also throw it from your own code if appropriate.

Comment: BTW you should no longer use `ParseException` with date parsing. The old and outdated classes `DateFormat` and `SimpleDateFormat` could throw it; but these days you should use the parse methods of the `java.time` classes for parsing dates and/or times. These throw an unchecked `DateTimeParseException` in case the string isn’t in the required date-time format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of Parse exception according to JAVA

> Signals that an error has been reached unexpectedly while parsing

As it clearly says, it throws an error while parsing
**Edited**
So parse use cases would be the following
Converting from String to date, String to any other format,pattern matcher,Object parsing to custom Objects etc...

You can refer here for any examples.....
http://www.javased.com/index.php?api=java.text.ParseException